# Segmentation Fault to Deallocate the Memory

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, malloc, memcpy

I have received the Segmentation Fault (Segfault) because of the free() function in the following code.

How the free() function can be used in this code without receiving the Segmentation Fault?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void driver_01(int* buf1, int buf1_size) {

    int* buf2 = (int*)malloc(buf1_size);
    //int* buf2 = new int(buf1_size);
    memcpy(&buf2, &buf1, buf1_size);
    
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < buf1_size; i++) {
        if (*(buf2 + i) != 0) {
            count++;
        }
        cout << *(buf2 + i) << endl;
    }
    cout << "Size of buf2: " << count << endl;

    free(buf2);
}

int main() {
    int buf1[8] = { 2, 6, 12, 15, 22, 30, 40, 50 };
    int buf1_size = sizeof(buf1) / sizeof(buf1[0]);

    cout << "Size of buf1: " << buf1_size << endl;

    driver_01(buf1, buf1_size);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Size of buf1: 8
2
6
12
15
22
30
40
50
Size of buf2: 8
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: In C++, don't use `malloc`/`free`. Avoid using `new`/`delete` as well. Use just `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Which C++ textbook taught you to use `malloc` and `free` in C++ code? You should throw away this textbook and get a better one. There is never a valid reason to use `malloc` and `free` in C++, that's for code written in C, a completely different language. Although the problem here is fairly simple, it came about because of completely unnecessary use of `malloc` and `free`. The best way to avoid bugs in C++ is to make it logically impossible for them to happen. It is logically impossible to have a bug that involves `malloc` and `free` if they are not used at all.

Comment: The `memcpy` copies `buf1_size` bytes from the pointer `buf1` over the pointer `buf2`. Hint: Note how I never say "from" or "to the memory *that x points to*".

Comment: Don't tag C++ with the very different language C.

Comment: memcpy comes from C. Note that in addition to what others have said, there are significant restrictions on the use of memcpy in C++. Unless you are very clear and careful about those issues, do not try to use it in C++. And even then, you probably don't really need to. (Admittedly, if you had used it correctly, this is a case where it would work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `malloc()` and `memcpy()` are both wrong.

- You are not allocating enough memory for the `buf2` array to copy the values from the `buf1` array. You are allocating space for only 8 bytes, not 8 `int`s.
- You are copying 8 bytes, not 8 `int`s, from the wrong source memory address (the address of the `buf1` parameter itself rather than the address of the array it points at), and writing them to the wrong destination memory address (the address of the `buf2` variable itself rather than the address of the array it points at), thus you are corrupting memory.

Try this instead:

```
void driver_01(int* buf1, int buf1_size) {

    int* buf2 = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * buf1_size);
    //int* buf2 = new int[buf1_size];
    memcpy(buf2, buf1, sizeof(int) * buf1_size);
    //std::copy_n(buf1, buf1_size, buf2);
  
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < buf1_size; i++) {
        if (buf2[i] != 0) {
            ++count;
        }
        cout << buf2[i] << endl;
    }
    /*
    int count = count_if(buf2, buf2 + buf1_size,
        [](int i){ return i != 0; });
    for_each(buf2, buf2 + buf1_size,
        [](int i){ cout << i << endl; });
    */

    cout << "Size of buf2: " << count << endl;

    free(buf2);
    //delete[] buf2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your actual problem is here

```
 memcpy(&buf2, &buf1, buf1_size);
```

you mean

```
 memcpy(buf2, buf1, buf1_size);
```

but as other have said, you must not use malloc or free in c++, you should use new and delete. but in this caese you should use std::vector

Edit. Your malloc is wrong too (thanks Remy). You need

```
 malloc(sizeof(int) * buf1_size)
```

Comment: The `memcpy()` isn't the only problem. The `malloc()` is also wrong.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thx I missed that